# how to convert .xlsx file to .mpp file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to convert `.xls`(microsoft excel) file in `.mpp`(microsoft project document) file in C# .

Comment: Be clear to ask questions. Say some useful lines about your problem

Comment: We can't answer from the details given: the excel spreadsheet could contain many things...

Comment: i need to select one heading with its full column and then transfer it into MS project as all the values of selected column will make out a task .. is it possible in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have Excel file and you want to convert it 
to Microsoft Project file using C#.

I did not find any built in functionality , so I think you have following options

1. Buy third party component
2. Create functionality that will do conversion based on office automation

Comment: it is not possible in without third party tool??

Comment: It's possible but I did not find any buil in functionality. So you will need develop framework , which read Excel file and create Microsoft Project File based on it.